# Can I "Pre-rotate" VBOs while loading them in LWJGL?

Tags: rotation, lwjgl, coordinates, vbo, rotate

It is possible to flip VBOs horizontally and vertically by swapping around destination coordinates.

Is it possible to rotate an image by any angle, such as 45 degrees, using different destination coordinates when loading up a VBO?

I realise that rotating present VBOs can easily be done using a matrix uniform in your vertex shader, but I'm asking about pre-loaded (VBOs) rotations; the VBO that you load being permanently rotated by X degrees.

*I am not looking for code but a conceptual method (or an explanation of why this isn't possible).*

Comment: I will ask the obvious question: why can't you use a shader uniform?

Comment: @SethBattin, lets assume that arrows go in one of 4 *diagonal* directions. Why upload an entire transformation matrix, which is 16 floats, when one can just have some additional VBOs?

Comment: How much memory would be used by additional VBOs?  Seem like it would be drastically more than 16 for any useful number of vertices.

Comment: That's a very good point. In my case, the VBOs are only 8 floats each though.